# Date/Time field is blank when user subscribes a report and receives the report in email

Tags: reporting

I have an issue when report is subscribed by the user and sent as an attachment in csv format.
The date/time fields start date and end date are visible to user when they view the report.
The fields are visible even if we download it as xlsx.
The issue occurs if the user subscribed the format as csv
[image]

Kindly let me know how to fix the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As per [KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V0000003zf4QAA), This seem to be expected behavior with csv file and has no fix.   You would need to use Formatted attachment option or Export the report manually.